# MongoDB schema diagram

Tags: mongodb

1. Would diagramming mongodb schema in a class diagram (UML format) be feasible as ER diagrams relate more to SQL.
2. When representing the id in a high level schema, which of the following 3 has the correct type: (int or objectId or _id)

   ```
   id: int
   ```

   OR

   ```
   id: bson.ObjectId
   ```

   OR

   ```
   id: _id
   ```
3. When representing a subdocument object in a schema diagram, which of the following 2 has the correct type (String or Object)

   ```
   comments : String [
                       {
                         userName : String
                         date : String
                         actualComment : String
                       }
                     ]
   ```

   OR

   ```
   comments : Object [
                       {
                         userName : String
                         date : String
                         actualComment : String
                       }
                     ]
   ```

---

**UPDATE**

If I have the following subdocument (here is JSON representation), how does Mongo store the replies - what type would it be?

```
    comments : String [
                        {
                          userName : String
                          date : String
                          actualComment : String
                          replies : comment [ ] // how does mongo store nested replies
                        }
                      ]
```

Comment: The _id is implicitly part of every document. So you might consider to omit it, unless you replace it with an application-specific value.

Comment: @Philipp The question is what type. `_id` is an implicit field, but the type is `ObjectId`.

Comment: How about the replies and comments. In JSON the replies takes the comment type but how is it represented in mongo?

Answer (score 4):

A UML class diagram is for classes in object-oriented programming and an ER diagram is for relations in a relational database. MongoDB is neither an object database nor a relational database, so neither tool is really a good fit for MongoDB. But given only those two tools, I would rather use UML class diagrams, because ER emphasizes something which should best be avoided in MongoDB: relations between documents.

By default, the _id field is filled with a generated value of type BSON ObjectId, so your second example `bson.ObjectId` would be technically correct if you use the default. However, you don't *have* to use the default. You can also explicitly set your _id fields to an own value of any type you want. So if you want to use integers for your ObjectId's for some reason (remember that you then need to take care of keeping them unique), you can of course do so and should say so in your documentation. When you don't use custom values for your _id's and also otherwise don't make any use of them, you might consider to just omit them from your diagrams, because they are implied.

In my opinion, embedded documents are best expressed in UML class diagrams by using composition (black-diamond arrow), while referenced documents are expressed using aggregation (white-diamond arrow). A sub-document is definitely not a `String`. `Object` is better, but even better would be to use the correct type.

Regarding your follow-up question: infinitely nested data structures (comments with an array of comments with an array of comments...) can be visualize in UML  through a composition arrow pointing back at the box it comes from. But keep in mind that such data structures are a bad fit for MongoDB and usually best avoided. I would rather recommend you to put each comment into an own document which references the topic it belongs to and the parent comment (aggregation). But even that's not a particularly elegant solution. MongoDB isn't built for storing graphs.

Answer (score 1):

1. Feasible, but not suitable in all cases. [FK relationships can be represented the same way. For arrays, embedded, etc. you'd have to establish a representation/interpretation.](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/applications/data-models-relationships/)
2. `ObjectID` is the type; that's a [BSON type](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/bson-types/). `_id` is the field name. No idea how got behind `int`, BSON types are *32 bit integer* and *64 bit integer*.
3. None of them. It's a simply a (sub)document.

---

**UPDATE**

It's an array technically. No specific type. In that case you probably were thinking of an array of `id`s of comment entities, but could be anything you want I think (including subdocuments).

Comment: Thanks,
if i have the following subdocument (here is JSON representation), how does mongo store the replies - what type would it be?

        comments : String [
                            {
                              userName : String
                              date : String
                              actualComment : String
                              replies : comment [ ] // how does mongo store nexted replies
                            }
                  ]

Comment: i reported as an answer as i couldn't format correctly in this comment

Comment: @tyonne when you have a followup question, ask a new question.

Comment: I copied the content of your *answer* to your question. That's how it should be done. Please delete your answer.